# How to get Json response using Alomofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a json response like this;

```
{
    "new1": [
        {
            "id": 249,
            "type": "Header",
            "label": "Başlık12",
            "isRequired": False,
            "sequence": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 254,
            "type": "NumberInput",
            "label": "numerik",
            "isRequired": False,
            "sequence": 6
        }
    ],
    "new2": [
        {
            "id": 256,
            "type": "Header",
            "label": "Başlık12",
            "isRequired": False,
            "sequence": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 259,
            "type": "Checkbox",
            "label": "Checkbox",
            "isRequired": True,
            "sequence": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

if ı use .responseJSON ı get failure Alamofire.AFError responseSerializationFailed. I also use .responseString(encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) but ıt returns as string all data. How can ı solve this problem.

Comment: I think it should be true/false instead of True/False

Comment: Thanks ı try without  "isRequired" field ıt is works. You are right.